# Typescript promises causes code to silently crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to use the async/await syntax to resolve a promise in typescript. I have experience in javascript, so I assume it is very similar, but I can't get around this bug. I am trying to use await on an asynchronous function, but the code will not continue running if I do it. For example, I have this code:

```
const strategies = await Strategy.getActiveStrategies();
```

In my Strategy model, I have this code segment (implemented using Mongoose):

```
public static async getActiveStrategies(filter = {}): Promise<Strategy[]> {
    return StrategyModel.find(filter).then(result => { 
    // note, the the .then doesn't matter; I can't even console.log(result) except 
    // in my test cases.
      return result.map(internalModel => {
        let strategy = new Strategy();
        strategy.setInternalModel(internalModel);
        return strategy;
      });
    });
}
```

No matter how I change the syntax, it will not work. I can change the .then(...) to async/await, and it will stop running at the 'await' line. I can change the first code block to `strategy.getActiveStrategies.then(activeStrategies => {...})`, and it still does not run any code in the 'then' function. I've even tried doing:

```
const strategy = Strategy.getActiveStrategies();
console.log(strategy) // prints: Promise { <pending> }
await strategy // does not continue running after this line.
```

I've tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to work. What's even more weird is that the code passes all of my test cases (I did test-driven development). For example, one part of my test cases is:

```
const found = await Strategy.getAllStrategies();
expect(found.length).toEqual(2);
```

And everything works as you would expect. I have multiple test cases that work. But, when I try to call the function in the main app, it just does not work.

What am I doing wrong? I've worked with MongoDB, mongoose, and JavaScript on previous projects, and I feel like what I'm trying to do is pretty simple. I'm lost on how to continue; I've looked on StackOverflow and other online resources, and I can't find anybody who has a similar problem as me. Any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if you need any more details. Thank you.

Comment: You have `.then`s and `await`s, but no `catch`es. Catch errors and log them, might be something.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you for the suggestion. I added a `.catch(err => console.log(err)` and still nothing. I have no idea what's going on when I call the function.

Comment: what if `StrategyModel.find(filter)` returns a rejected promise? Try adding the rejected condition. ie: `StrategyModel.find(filter).then(result => ...., err => console.log(err))`

Comment: are your test cases using the same db as the app?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks again for the suggestion. I wasn't 100% sure what you meant, so I've tried your suggestion with the following code block:  `return StrategyModel.find(obj).then(result => {return result.map(internalModel => { let strategy = new Strategy();
          strategy.setInternalModel(internalModel);  return strategy;});})
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);  return [];});` It still does not log anything. Sorry for the formatting; this is my first post here.

Comment: @ABOS I use MongoMemoryServer. So it's not exactly the same, but it's similar. The database seems to work (on some things) because I call the database earlier in the code.

Comment: @AustinStarks, what does it show when you run query directly on mongodb with given filter?

Comment: @ABOS It gives the result array as you would expect.

Comment: @AustinStarks, since you are using physically different dbs for tests and app, in order to narrow down the issue,  perhaps you can try tests with actual db? or in memory db for the main app?

Comment: I figured out the problem. Much much earlier in the code, I had a promise that I should've used "await" on. Thanks again for your suggestions. I appreciate it.